# How to use LayerNormBasicLSTMCell in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, normalization, lstm, layer

I am trying to use 'tf.contrib.rnn.LayerNormBasicLSTMCell' to shorten the time required for training LSTM cell.

Before using LayerNormBasicLSTMCell, I have used 'tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell', and the following code works very fine.

```py
class Model():

    def __init__(self, args, infer=False):

        ''' Some definitions are here '''  

        cell_fn = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell

        def get_cell():
            return cell_fn(args.rnn_size)

        cell = get_cell()

        if (infer == False and args.keep_prob < 1):  # training mode
            cell = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(cell, output_keep_prob=args.keep_prob)
        self.cell = cell

        # Cell states : batch_size x (1, cell.state_size)
        zero_state = tf.split(tf.zeros([args.batch_size, cell.state_size]), axis=0, num_or_size_splits=args.batch_size)
        self.state_in = tf.identity(zero_state, name='state_in')
        self.state_out = tf.split(tf.zeros([args.batch_size, cell.state_size]), axis=0, num_or_size_splits=args.batch_size)
        self.output_states = tf.split(tf.zeros([args.batch_size, args.rnn_size]), axis=0, num_or_size_splits=args.batch_size)


        ''' Some definitions are here '''

        for b in range(args.batch_size):

            # current embedding sequence : (seq_length x rnn_size)
            current_emd_seq = embedding_seqs[b]

            for f in range(args.seq_length):

                # current embedding frame : (1 x rnn_size)
                current_emd_frame = tf.reshape(current_emd_seq[f], shape=(1, args.rnn_size))


                with tf.variable_scope("rnnlm") as scope:
                    if (b > 0 or f > 0):
                        scope.reuse_variables()

                # go through LSTM cell
                self.output_states[b], zero_state[b] = cell(current_emd_frame, zero_state[b])
```

However, if I just changed the code line from

```py
cell_fn = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell
```

to

```py
cell_fn = tf.contrib.rnn.LayerNormBasicLSTMCell
```

the following error occurs...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dooseop/Projects/__IRLLSTM__/version20/kitti_train.py", 
line 192, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/dooseop/Projects/__IRLLSTM__/version20/kitti_train.py", line 95, in main
    train(args)
  File "/home/dooseop/Projects/__IRLLSTM__/version20/kitti_train.py", line 112, in train
    model = Model(args)
  File "/home/dooseop/Projects/__IRLLSTM__/version20/kitti_model.py", line 193, in __init__
    self.output_states[b], zero_state[b] = cell(current_emd_frame, zero_state[b])
  File "/home/dooseop/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py", line 1099, in __call__
    output, new_state = self._cell(inputs, state, scope=scope)
  File "/home/dooseop/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py", line 232, in __call__
    return super(RNNCell, self).__call__(inputs, state)
  File "/home/dooseop/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py", line 714, in __call__
    outputs = self.call(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dooseop/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/python/ops/rnn_cell.py", line 1431, in 
call
    c, h = state
  File "/home/dooseop/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 401, in __iter__
    "Tensor objects are not iterable when eager execution is not "
TypeError: Tensor objects are not iterable when eager execution is not 
enabled. To iterate over this tensor use tf.map_fn.
```

I also tried changing the sizes of zero_state, self.state_out, the result is the same.

For example, change

```
zero_state = tf.split(tf.zeros([args.batch_size, cell.state_size]), axis=0, num_or_size_splits=args.batch_size)
```

to

```
zero_state = tf.split(tf.zeros([args.batch_size, args.rnn_size, 2]), axis=0, num_or_size_splits=args.batch_size)
```

or

```
zero_state = tf.split(tf.zeros([args.batch_size, 2* args.rnn_size]), axis=0, num_or_size_splits=args.batch_size)
```

Please let me know what is the problem of my usage...Thanks!!

Comment: Using layer normalization in tensorflow can be done via `tf.contrib.rnn.LayerNormBasicLSTMCell` where you have to pass the `num_units` which is the number of units in the LSTM cell.
In your code, you didn't provide any argument for that.

Comment: Hi! Attaching relevant threads for reference .            
https://pretagteam.com/question/how-to-use-layernormbasiclstmcell-in-tensorflow  https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/nn/rnn_cell/LSTMCell